A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed Imap Outlook
This is my first time asking a question here. If anything is missing, please let me know
I have a Spring Boot application, and I want this application to read Outlook emails using IMAP. For this, I registered the application in Azure AD, and I am receiving the token. The token also contains the permissions. However, when I try to run the code below with this token, I get the error "A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed."
Below are the Spring Boot code, YAML file, and log.
I would like to know where I might be going wrong.
spring:
security:
oauth2:

  client:

    registration:

      azure:

        client-id: *****

        client-secret: ******

        authorization-grant-type: authorization_code

        scope: "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"

        redirect-uri: "http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/azure"

        provider: azure

    provider:

      azure:

        authorization-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

        token-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

        user-info-uri: https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo

        user-name-attribute: sub

public void connect(String userEmailId, String oauth2AccessToken) {
String host = "outlook.office365.com";

String port = "993";

Store store = null;

Properties props = new Properties();

props.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");

props.put("mail.imap.sasl.enable", "true");

props.put("mail.imap.port", port);

props.put("mail.imap.auth.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");

props.put("mail.imap.sasl.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");

props.put("mail.imap.auth.login.disable", "true");

props.put("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable", "true");

props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.port", port);

props.setProperty("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");

props.put("mail.debug", "true");

props.put("mail.debug.auth", "true");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props);

session.setDebug(true);

try {

    store = session.getStore("imap");

    store.connect(host, userEmailId, oauth2AccessToken);

    log.info("IMAP connected successfully!");

    if (store.isConnected()) {

        log.info("Connection Established successfully!");

    }

} catch (Exception e) {

    log.error("Store.Connect failed with the error: ", e);

} finally {

    if (store != null && store.isConnected()) {

        try {

            store.close();

        } catch (MessagingException e) {

            log.error("Failed to close store connection: ", e);

        }

    }

}

}
@GetMapping("/test")

public void test(@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("azure") OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient) throws Exception {

     String accessToken = authorizedClient.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();

    emailBasicAuthService.connect("test@comanyms.onmicrosoft.com",accessToken);

}

A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
10:45:03.250 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] ERROR c.e.service.EmailBasicAuthService 114 - Store.Connect failed with the error: AUTHENTICATE failed.
